# Find the value of $\sum_{d=0}^\infty\binom{d+m-1}{m-1}\frac{x^d}{d!}$.

Tags: combinatorics, taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, multisets

It is known that the generating function of the number of multisets is given by
$$
\sum_{d=0}^\infty\binom{d+m-1}{m-1}{x^d}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^m}.
$$
Then, does a similar series
$$
\sum_{d=0}^\infty\binom{d+m-1}{m-1}\frac{x^d}{d!}
$$ to the generating function have an explicit formula ?

Answer (score 5):

The series is a [confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function), or a [generalised hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) $_1F_1$:
$$\sum_{d = 0}^\infty {d+m-1 \choose m-1} \frac{x^d}{d!} = \sum_{d=0}^\infty \frac{(m)_d}{(1)_d} \frac{x^d}{d!} = {}_1F_1(m;1;x) = M(m,1,x),$$
where $(a)_n := a(a+1)\dots (a+n-1)$ denotes the rising factorial.

These functions are also related to the [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) $L_n$:
$${}_1F_1(m;1;x) = e^x L_{m-1}(-x).$$